# In iOS Textfield hides long text when its secure

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uifont

If text are long then textfield display blank. as like shown in below screen shot:
[image]

and after resign focus it seems like

[image]

I had set minimum font size to 10 and set autoresize text flag to TRUE. 
Can any one please help regarding this issue ?

Comment: Can you provide the code for dismissing the keyboard? I mean resign focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This scenario occurs only when we set custom height instead of default size.
for eg, default is 31 and you are setting more than it.

So, you can use it dynamically if you want more.

```
CGRect frameRect = textField.frame;
frameRect.size.height = 100(specify the height you want);
textField.frame = frameRect;
```

It may be helpful to you,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the following:

```
[myLabel setMinimumScaleFactor:0.5f];
[myLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
```